# How do I prove that these two subsets of $S^1$ are arcs intersecting endpoints?

Tags: general-topology

Let $C_1,C_2$ be subsets of $S^1$ such that $C_1\cup C_2=S^1$ and $C_1\cap C_2=\{a,b\}$ where $a\neq b$. Moreover, assume that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

How do I prove that there are injective paths $\alpha,\beta$ in $S^1$ such that $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)=a$ and $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)=b$ and their images are $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively?

This is intuitively clear, but find this really hard to prove.

Since $C_1,C_2$ are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, there exist injective paths $\alpha,\beta$ whose images are $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively.

How do I assert that $\alpha(0)=a$ or $b$?

Suppose $t_0\in [0,1]$ be the smallest number $\alpha$ intersecting $C_2$. Suppose $t_0>0$. Let $\pi$ be a simple loop in $S^1$ starting from $\alpha(0)$. Then when this loop is at $\alpha(t_0)$ the first time, this loop has two choices of routes to go so it must come back to $\alpha(t_0)$ at some another time, which is a contradiction.

The problem is, I have no idea how to formalize this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, this does seem trickier to formalize than it really ought to be!  I think intuitively the idea is captured up in the following:

**Lemma:** Any continuous bijection $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

**Proof:**  Wlog, we may assume that $f(0) < f(1)$.  If $f$ is not strictly increasing, we may find $0 < a < b < 1$ with $f(b) < f(a)$.  Assume that $f(0) < f(a)$.  Now $[f(0), f(a)] \subset f([0,a])$, while $[f(b), f(a)) \subset f((a, b])$.

So, $f([0,a]) \cap f((a,b]) \supset [f(b), f(a)) $, and in particular is not empty.  This contradicts the injectivity of $f$.

You should go ahead and fill in the other cases or convince yourself that they're essentially the same.

Basically, what the lemma is going to tell us is that any homeomorphism $\alpha:[0,1] \to C_1$ must either be positively oriented or negatively oriented.  It can't "switch" its orientation partway through the map.

Rotating if necessary, we may assume that $a = 1$.  Also assume that $\alpha$ is positively oriented.  Suppose that $1 \in \alpha(0,1) $.  Find a $t_0 \in (0,1)$ so that $\alpha(t_0) = 1$.  Suppose that $\alpha(1) \neq b$.  Consider please the segment $\alpha([t_0, 1])$.  Since $\alpha(1) \neq b$, we have that $\alpha(1) \notin C_2$.  So it must be the case that $\alpha([0, t_0))$ comes arbitrarily close to $\alpha(1)$ from the other side.  But then that would give $\alpha([0,1]) = S^1$, which cannot be true for two reasons.  If $b \neq \alpha(0)$ (since it's certainly not equal to one of them), we can argue similarly to get a contradiction.  Thus $1 = \alpha(0)$ or $1 = \alpha(1)$.

You should probably fill in the rest, but that's the gist of the argument; the map $\alpha$ must follow either a positive or negative orientation, which poses a problem if one of the points of intersection $a,b$ doesn't lie at the end of the parametrization by $\alpha$.  It requires that $\alpha$ wrap all the way around $S^1$, which we know can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You may let $\alpha$ be homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $C_1$ and $\beta$ be homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $C_2$. If you glue two sections identied *inner* point of first with any point of second, you cannot get a manifold as a result, so points $0$ and $1$ of each section map to the points $a$ and $b$. (maybe, $0\mapsto b$, but it is not essential detale)